# Can I substitute contested for rated?

Tags: word-usage

> Cake Wars is a game where fifteen participants are given sixty minutes to decorate a cake to a theme, after which the finished cakes are rated.

If the finished cakes are rated by the game's participants, then can I change "rated" to "contested" and is it better to do so?

Comment: Note about the title: "Substitute [X] for [Y]" means "replace [Y] with [X]," not the other way around.

Comment: Did you even look up the word "contested"? If so, what about the definition left you confused about whether or not it works in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Contested" means to be disputed and ultimately challenged, so I would not use that word there. The game itself is a contest, however, so you could incorporate that word instead:

> Cake Wars is a contest between fifteen bakers who are given sixty minutes and a theme to make a cake.

The use of the word "contest" affords us the opportunity to shorthand this a bit and omit obvious things like scoring the cakes and awarding a winner which are part and parcel of contests.

To better understand how "contested" would be used, consider this:

> The results of the game were contested by Michael, who felt the winner did not play by the rules.

Answer (score 3):

No.  The word has a different meaning, and you should check the dictionary for the meaning of the adjective "contested", or the related verb "(to) contest".

If I "rate" a cake, then I judge how good, or bad, it is.

If I "contest" a cake... it doesn't have a normal meaning: Either I question it's correctness (??)  "I contested my teacher's rule banning red socks"...  That doesn't make sense.... or I strive to maintain control of the cake.  That just about makes sense:  "The twins were contesting the birthday cake, each claiming that to have the right to a larger slice".

In your context, it doesn't make sense at all.  "To contest" never means "to rate".